# after joining three query not getting proper result in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three queries like this:

```
select count(*) as receved from transaction_tbl where locid=6 and status=0 
Result 
receved 
3

select count(*) as parked  from transaction_tbl where locid=6 and status=2
result 
parked  
48

select count(*) as requested from transaction_tbl where locid=6 and status=3
result
requested 
5
```

i want join these three queries,so i wrote query like this:

```
select count(*) as receved,count(*) as parked,count(*) as requested 
from transaction_tbl where locid=6 and status in(0,2,3) group by status
```

but now i got the result something like this

```
receved     parked      requested
----------- ----------- -----------
3           3           3
5           5           5
48          48          48
```

and i trye query like this:

```
select count(*) as receved, count(*) as parked, count(*) as requested 
from transaction_tbl
where locid = 6 and status in (0,2,3);
```

but this time also am getting wrong result:
if any help is very appreciable:

i want answer like this:

```
 receved     parked      requested
 ----------- ----------- -----------
3             48           5
```

so how i can re-write the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe like this:

```
select sum(status_receved) as receved, sum(status_parked) as parked, sum(status_requested) as requested from (select case when (status = 0) then 1 else 0 end as status_receved,
case when (status = 2) then 1 else 0 end as status_parked, 
case when (status = 3) then 1 else 0 end as status_requested 
from transaction_tbl where locid = 6 and status in (0,2,3)) a;
```

Comment: yes sir this is worked fine..thanks for help..shall be very thank full to you

Answer (score 1):

If you want one row in the output, then remove the `group by` statement.  This will be an aggregation query that treats the entire table as a single group and returns one row:

```
select count(*) as receved, count(*) as parked, count(*) as requested 
from transaction_tbl
where locid = 6 and status in (0,2,3);
```